# How to change the Chapter Num font when using fncychap?

Tags: fonts, chapters, fncychap

I'm using fncychap to style my chapter titles :

```
\usepackage[Sonny]{fncychap}
%-----------
\ChNameVar{\Huge\fontfamily{put}\selectfont\color{black}}
\ChNumVar{\Huge\fontfamily{pzc}\selectfont\color{blue}}
\ChTitleVar{\Huge\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont\scshape\color{green}}
```

and this is what I get as a result : 
[image]

I didn't understand how the ChNameVar, ChNumVar and ChTitleVar work, and my question is : How can I increase the size of the chapter num. " 1 " in this case, to make it bigger ...

EDIT : Also as you can see the chapter title is not green what I'm doing wrong in this case ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That number is  set by `\ChNumVar` and you use Zapf Chancery. Comment that line or choose one of the other font families:

```
\documentclass[french]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage[Sonny]{fncychap}
%-----------
\ChNameVar{\Huge\fontfamily{put}\selectfont\color{black}}%  Utopia
\ChNumVar{\Huge\fontfamily{pzc}\selectfont\color{blue}}% Zapf
\ChTitleVar{\Huge\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont\scshape\color{green}}% Helvetica

\begin{document}

\chapter {Contexte}\noindent\Large
\fontfamily{put}\selectfont ABCDEFGHIabcdefghj0123456\\
\fontfamily{pzc}\selectfont ABCDEFGHIabcdefghj0123456\\
\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont ABCDEFGHIabcdefghj0123456\\

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: the problem is that I can't even see the green color, and I alway get the chapter Title and the chapter num with the same color ...

Comment: Then create a _complete_ example which shows your behaviour. Otherwise we can help only with a crystal ball ...